# Have an unknown IP address, how can I discover what it is?

Tags: ip

I don't have any knowledge about networks, but I noticed that my internet is rather laggy and slow.

I tried performing a `tracert` to a particular IP which is used by my Service Provider and after 6 hops it reached the destination.

Now I have an IP Address, which I wish to discover what is it (switch or something like that). Is there a command that will help me discover what it is? I know it is local `192.168.x.x` but I cannot find its "name"

Hope you can understand me, and hope it's in the right forum.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off topic here, you can consider asking this on [su].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A switch won't show up as a hop in a traceroute. I'll bet it's your home gateway/router that was supplied by your provider.

Here are some very basic test steps... first, do an `ipconfig` and check to see if the IP address is that of your "Default Gateway". The default gateway is the first router you hop over, and this will be inside your home. If not, try to go to `http://192.168.x.x` and `https://192.168.x.x`. If both those fail, `ping 192.168.x.x`, then `arp -a`, find the MAC address associated with the IP, and try to find it on here: http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl. That hopefully will at least tell you the vendor of the device.

If all else fails, install `nmap` for Windows: https://nmap.org/download.html#windows, then: `nmap -P0 -O 192.168.x.x`, which will possibly tell you the Operating System running on the device.

If you're still nowhere, `nmap -sS -P0 192.168.x.x` will show you a list of any open ports on the device that you can attempt to connect to.

Comment: I got a good hint with "http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl"! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know your PC's IP address, type ipconfig in a command window.

If you want to know what public IP address you appear to the world as, go to Google and search on "what is my IP"

Comment: Your own IP won't show up in a `traceroute`. A trace contains the IP addresses of router 'hops'. Also, "What is my IP" aka http://wimi.com shows you your external (ie. public) IP address after the internal has been NAT'd, so that won't help at all.